# How to preset the value in JQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

The values from the datepicker fields are appended to the final url as a parameter which is sent to an external website.

I need to preset the value as tomorrows date (today +1) within the 'check-in' datepicker.

When writing HTML, I would use `<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John">` to preset the value. But this does not work within my JQuery Datepicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    var startDateTextBox = jQuery('#checkinDate');
    var endDateTextBox = jQuery('#checkoutDate');

    startDateTextBox.datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            if (endDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                var testStartDate = startDateTextBox.datetimepicker('getDate');
                var testEndDate = endDateTextBox.datetimepicker('getDate');
                if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                    endDateTextBox.datetimepicker('setDate', testStartDate);
            }
            else {
                endDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            }
        },
        onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){
            endDateTextBox.datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', startDateTextBox.datetimepicker('getDate') );
        }
    });
    endDateTextBox.datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            if (startDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                var testStartDate = startDateTextBox.datetimepicker('getDate');
                var testEndDate = endDateTextBox.datetimepicker('getDate');
                if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                    startDateTextBox.datetimepicker('setDate', testEndDate);
            }
            else {
                startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            }
        },
        onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){
            startDateTextBox.datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', endDateTextBox.datetimepicker('getDate') );
        }
    });
});
</script>
<form name="searchForm" method="get" action="https://www.example.com/Search" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <input type="hidden" name="locale" value="en-US" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" data-id="spiritCode" name="spiritCode" value="repph" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="location" value="myvalue" data-value="mydat-" id="location" data-cacheable="true" autocomplete="off">
[row width="full-width" v_align="middle" padding="0 0px 0px 0px"]
[col span="4" span__sm="6" padding="0 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]
Check-In Date <input type="text" autocomplete="off" data-cacheable="true" name="checkinDate" id="checkinDate" data-iso-value="" />

[/col]
[col span="4" span__sm="6" padding="0 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]

Check-Out Date<input type="text" autocomplete="off" data-cacheable="true" name="checkoutDate" id="checkoutDate" data-iso-value="" />

[/col]
[col span="4" span__sm="12" padding="0 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]

Room <input data-id="rooms" name="rooms" type="number" value="1" data-value="" min="1" max="2" data-cacheable="true">

[/col]


[/row]
[row width="full-width" v_align="middle" padding="0 0px 0px 0px"]

[col span="4" span__sm="12" padding="0 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]

Adults <input data-id="adults" name="adults" type="number" value="1" data-value="" min="1" max="6" data-cacheable="true">

[/col]
[col span="4" span__sm="12" padding="0 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]

Child <input data-id="kids" name="kids" type="number" value="0" data-value="" min="0" max="4" data-cacheable="true">

[/col]
[col span="4" span__sm="12" padding="0 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]

Rate <select data-id="rate"  name="rate">
         <option selected="selected" value="Standard">None</option>
         <option value="Govt">Government</option>
         <option value="Veteran">Veteran</option>
         <option value="AAA">AAA / CAA Member</option>
         <option value="Senior">Senior</option>
     </select>

[/col]
[col span="4" span__sm="12" padding="20px 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"][/col]
[col span="4" span__sm="12" padding="20px 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]

<button type="submit" class="quickbookSearchFormButton button-shop button-block" style="background-color: #ffb612; color: #000; width: 100%; font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;">Book Now</button>

[/col]
[col span="4" span__sm="12" padding="20px 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"][/col]
[/row]
</form>
```

Comment: which versions of jquery and datepicker are you using? can you link to them?

Comment: jquery-1.10.2.min.js , jquery-ui-timepicker-addon, jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js, jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: your're missing the datepicker library. Perhaps that is why it isn't working as expected?